# Access a amazon s3 bucket subfolder using python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to access a bucket subfolder using python's boto3.

The problem is that I cannot find anywhere how to input the subfolder information inside the boto code.

All I find is how to put the bucket name, but I do not have access to the whole bucket, just to a specific subfolder. Can anyone give me a light?

What I did so far:

```
 BUCKET = "folder/subfolder"
 conn = S3Connection(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET)
 bucket = conn.get_bucket(BUCKET)
 for key in bucket.list():
     print key.name.encode('utf-8')
```

The error messages:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied
```

I do not need to use boto for the operation, I just need to list/get the files inside this subfolder.

P.S.: I can access the files using **cyberduck** by putting the path `folder/subfolder`, which means I have access to the date.

Sincerely,

Israel

Comment: Your code seems to be for Boto 2.x, rather than Boto 3.

Comment: Can you show me where I can find the information to access the subfolder using boto 3? I did not find it in the manual. :(

Comment: I'm bit confused about your problem. What do you mean by *"putting"* in *"using cyberduck by putting the path `folder/subfolder`"*? Where do you put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem using something similar vtl suggested:

I had to put the prefix in my bucket and a delimiter. The final code was something like this:

```
objects = s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucketName, Prefix=bucketPath+'/', Delimiter='/')
```

As he said, there's not folder structure, then you have to state a delimiter and also put it after the ***Prefix*** like I did.

Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="your_subfolder"):
    do_something()
```

AWS doesn't actually have a directory structure - it just fakes one by putting "/"s in names. The `Prefix` option restricts the search to all objects whose name starts with the given prefix, which should be your "subfolder".

Comment: boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden

Comment: I got this message now